# Convert one sql cell data into multiple rows and two columns

Tags: sql-server, datetime, split

I have a SQL table in which I have a `nvarchar(MAX)` column where multiple barcodes and their datetime values are stored in this format:

```
2238455|12/10/2019 03:07:55 PM;2238452|12/10/2019 03:13:39 PM;2238454|12/10/2019 03:25:04 PM;2238453|12/10/2019 03:26:44 PM**
```

A barcode and its datetime are separated from other barcodes using a semicolon `;` while a barcode and its datetime are separated using pipe `|`.

I want to show them in two columns barcode and datetime. Something like this.

```
Barcode  DateTime
-------------------------------
2238455  12/10/2019 03:07:55 PM
2238452  12/10/2019 03:13:39 PM
2238454  12/10/2019 03:25:04 PM
2238453  12/10/2019 03:26:44 PM
```

Number of barcodes in one cell are not fixed, it can vary. Is this possible to convert this data into the desired format? I want to write a stored procedure or a view.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Answer (score 1):

If you use SQL Server 2016+, you may try the following approach using `STRING_SPLIT()`:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   TextData nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO Data 
   (TextData)
VALUES
   (N'2238455|12/10/2019 03:07:55 PM;2238452|12/10/2019 03:13:39 PM;2238454|12/10/2019 03:25:04 PM;2238453|12/10/2019 03:26:44 PM')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   LEFT(s.[value], CHARINDEX(N'|', s.[value]) - 1) AS Barcode,
   RIGHT(s.[value], LEN(s.[value]) - CHARINDEX(N'|', s.[value])) AS [DateTime]
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(d.TextData, N';') s
```

Result:

```
Barcode DateTime
2238455 12/10/2019 03:07:55 PM
2238452 12/10/2019 03:13:39 PM
2238454 12/10/2019 03:25:04 PM
2238453 12/10/2019 03:26:44 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

For older versions, you can use this function to convert the string to table

```
create Function [dbo].[fn_StringToTable] 
(
    @List Varchar(max)
)
RETURNS @Table TABLE (barcode VARCHAR(100), newdate VARCHAR(100))
AS
BEGIN
    IF RIGHT(@List, 1) <> ';'
    SELECT @List = @List + ';'

    DECLARE @Pos    BIGINT,
            @OldPos BIGINT,
            @rowval varchar(100)
    SELECT  @Pos    = 1,
            @OldPos = 1

    WHILE   @Pos < LEN(@List)
        BEGIN
            SELECT @Pos = CHARINDEX(';', @List, @OldPos)
            select @rowval = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, @OldPos, @Pos - @OldPos)))

            INSERT INTO @Table(barcode, newdate)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@rowval,1,CHARINDEX('|',@rowval)-1),
                   SUBSTRING(@rowval,CHARINDEX('|',@rowval)+1,LEN(@rowval)) 

            SELECT  @OldPos = @Pos + 1
        END

    RETURN
END
```

Then call this function with string

```
select * from  [dbo].[fn_StringToTable] ('2238455|12/10/2019 03:07:55 PM;2238452|12/10/2019 03:13:39 PM;2238454|12/10/2019 03:25:04 PM;2238453|12/10/2019 03:26:44 PM')
```

OutPut

```
barcode newdate
2238455 12/10/2019 03:07:55 PM
2238452 12/10/2019 03:13:39 PM
2238454 12/10/2019 03:25:04 PM
2238453 12/10/2019 03:26:44 PM
```